# How to display particular stuff of the registered person in profile page - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a member table, I want to fetch and display some of the fieldsets like fullname , email and phone number in the profile page.

i had tried some of the codes using object.all() as well as using primary keys but i don't get the desired output .

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      member = Member( fullname=request.POST.get('fullname'), companyname=request.POST.get('companyname'),Email=request.POST.get('email'),password=request.POST.get('password'),contactno=request.POST.get('contactno'),role=request.POST.get('role'),)
      member.save()
     return redirect('/')
else:
    return render(request, 'web/index.html')
```

models.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
   fullname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    companyname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   contactno = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='anything')
```

Comment: you can give more information or your code

Comment: Is your indentation that bad in your code too? Or did you just mess up the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the generic 'CreateView' https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/ for model's create form.

Comment: FieldError at /web/profile/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: Email, companyname, contactno, fullname, id, password........i tried with fullname also then only it showing error

Comment: Please provide your model code in the question. I have just given the example. And how member model is related to the User (built in Django model) model.

Comment: okay sir now i updated the code. can you please check that and if you have any idea please let me know sir ,